# How to convert mysql query to jpa named query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have one `Order` table

> order_id | customer_id | submit_date | order_number | ....

currently I am fetching all records based on `customer_id` by using `jpa named query`

```
public List<Order> readOrders(Long customerId){
 Query query = em.createNamedQuery("select order from com.mycompany.Order where order.customer.id = :customerId");
 query.setParameter("customerId", customerId);
 return query.getResultLis();
}
```

above query is working fine and it is fetching all records from db, but my task is to fetch the records only from past `15 days` for this I know the `sql query`

```
select * from Oder where SUBMI_DATE between date_sub(sydate(), interval 15 day) and sydate() and customer_id = 101;
```

above `sql query` is working fine but my problem I don't know how to convert above `sql query` to `jpa named query` can anyone please help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your object equivalent of sql `SUBMI_DATE` is `submitDate`

```
public List<Order> readOrders(Long customerId){
  Query query = em.createNamedQuery("select order from com.mycompany.Order where order.customer.id = :customerId and order.submitDate > :specificDate");
  // I use Joda time you can use java.util.Date directly
  DateTime specificDate= new DateTime().minusDays(15);

  query.setParameter("customerId", customerId);
  query.setParameter("specificDate", specificDate.toDate(),TemporalType.DATE);

 return query.getResultLis();
}
```